# Error in connecting domain name to nginx

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I'm trying to connect my droplets on Digital Ocean to a domain name (example.com)

Currently using uwsgi, nginx and the web apps is in python (flask, MySQL)

I have configured my project .conf as such:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip-address example.com www.example.com;
}

location {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///home/user/example/example.sock;
}
```

I have added hosts:
127.0.0.1 perhatian.com www.perhatian.com

The site currently is not reachable, however, when i access the IP its working.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have proper DNS setup towards that domain name (perhatian.com) as seen from https://intodns.com/perhatian.com

If you are trying to load perhatian.com in a browser from any where, you'll need to setup A records pointing towards the servers IP on which you are able to load the website.

Comment: Yes, I just found the problem. Thanks!